# Dynamically get the powershell script name in scripts help example section

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Is there a possibility to dynamically add the .ps1 filename to the scripts help section?

I am trying to put examples in the help section of my script and always show the current filename, in case a customer changes it.

Like this:

```
<#
.EXAMPLE
 .\$name -param1 xxx
\#>
```

and if i run

> get-help .\my_script.ps1 -examples

the output should look like

```
EXAMPLE
.\my_script.ps1 -param1 xxx
```

I am not sure if this is possible inside of a comment

but get-help has the possibility to detect the filename

if you run

> get-help .\filename.ps1

its name is added to the syntax section

you could also run

> get-help .\filename.ps1 | select *

and you'll see that the name is part of the output so maybe this is usable somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

To produce the script's path and filename

```
$pscommandpath
```

If you want JUST the filename:

```
Split-Path -leaf $PSCommandpath
```

Comment: nope sorry, this does not work inside the example area, I've already tried that. this just works in the normal script area